# ¿Cómo ejecutar un bucle dentro de un elemento HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Intento ejecutar un bucle conformado por un elemento HTML, es decir que en la estructura podría tener

```html
<div>
    {%
        for(let i = 0; 5>i; i++)
        ?=
            <p>${i}</p>
        =?
    %}
</div>
```

Y tendría que resultar

```
<div>
    <p>0</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
</div>
```

Lo que tengo hasta ahora es

```js
NodeList.prototype.indexOf = function (s) {
    let found = false;
    let ind = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        const el = this[i];
        if (found === false) {
            if (el === s) {
                found = true;
                ind = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return ind;
};

const h = document.querySelector("html");
h.innerHTML = h.innerHTML.replaceAll("{%", "<loopstamp>").replaceAll("%}", "</loopstamp>").replaceAll("?=", "<htmlstamp>").replaceAll("=?", "</htmlstamp>");
        document.querySelectorAll("loopstamp").forEach(el => {
            const final = `document.writeElement = function(t, i, s) {if (document.querySelectorAll(t)[i].querySelector("loopstamp").querySelector("htmlstamp")) {document.querySelectorAll(t)[i].querySelector("loopstamp").innerHTML = ""};document.querySelectorAll(t)[i].querySelector("loopstamp").innerHTML += s;}\n`+el.textContent.split("\n").filter(e => e.replaceAll(" ", "") !== "")[0].trim() + "{\n" + "document.writeElement('"+el.parentNode.tagName+"', "+el.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(el.parentNode.tagName).indexOf(el.parentNode)+", `"+el.querySelector("htmlstamp").innerHTML + "`);\n}";
            new Function(final)();
           el.parentNode.innerHTML = el.parentNode.innerHTML.replace("<loopstamp>", "<div>").replace("</loopstamp>", "</div>");
        });
```

```html
<div>
    {%
        for(let i = 0; 5>i; i++)
        ?=
            <p>${i}</p>
        =?
    %}
</div>
```

Este código va reemplazando

| Texto | Texto reemplazado |
| --- | --- |
| {% | `<loopstamp>` |
| %} | `</loopstamp>` |
| ?= | `<htmlstamp>` |
| =? | `</htmlstamp>` |

De manera que puedo recorrer cada `loopstamp` y saber cuál es el bucle puesto y después añadirle el contenido de `<htmlstamp>` y finalmente ejecutar una función que hará que el bucle haga efecto

El problema es que solo funciona con un bucle por etiqueta, si pongo dos en una misma etiqueta da un error

```js
NodeList.prototype.indexOf = function (s) {
    let found = false;
    let ind = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        const el = this[i];
        if (found === false) {
            if (el === s) {
                found = true;
                ind = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return ind;
};

const h = document.querySelector("html");
h.innerHTML = h.innerHTML.replaceAll("{%", "<loopstamp>").replaceAll("%}", "</loopstamp>").replaceAll("?=", "<htmlstamp>").replaceAll("=?", "</htmlstamp>");
        document.querySelectorAll("loopstamp").forEach(el => {
            const final = `document.writeElement = function(t, i, s) {if (document.querySelectorAll(t)[i].querySelector("loopstamp").querySelector("htmlstamp")) {document.querySelectorAll(t)[i].querySelector("loopstamp").innerHTML = ""};document.querySelectorAll(t)[i].querySelector("loopstamp").innerHTML += s;}\n`+el.textContent.split("\n").filter(e => e.replaceAll(" ", "") !== "")[0].trim() + "{\n" + "document.writeElement('"+el.parentNode.tagName+"', "+el.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(el.parentNode.tagName).indexOf(el.parentNode)+", `"+el.querySelector("htmlstamp").innerHTML + "`);\n}";
            new Function(final)();
           el.parentNode.innerHTML = el.parentNode.innerHTML.replace("<loopstamp>", "<div>").replace("</loopstamp>", "</div>");
        });
```

```html
<div>
    {%
        for(let i = 0; 5>i; i++)
        ?=
            <p>${i}</p>
        =?
    %}
    {%
        for(let i = 0; 5>i; i++)
        ?=
            <p>${i}</p>
        =?
    %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te había comentado en otra respuesta, es mucho mejor trabajar con cadenas que directamente sobre elementos del DOM. Sin embargo, creo que tu error está en que usas algunos `querySelectorAll()` y `replaceAll()`, pero no me creas mucho, porque realmente no entendí tu código y me fui directamente por una opción diferente:

Deberías analizar lo que hay realmente en cada ciclo, cómo debe empezar, en qué momento debe terminar y lo que se va a hacer con la variable en cada iteración.

Esta propuesta está formulada rápidamente y sin detenerme en detalles como que la condición debe ser "variable - operador - valor", por ejemplo `i>5` y no al revés `5<i`.

Desde el principio quise hacerlo con expresiones regulares, pero tal vez podrían omitirse, sobre todo, después de que falló épicamente desde la primera parte y, en mi defensa, debo argumentar que no soy muy versado sobre el tema.

No es lo único a tener en cuenta, seguramente habrá otras cosas por mejorar o corregir, pero eso ya te queda como ejercicio propio.

```js
const parseLoop = loop => {
    // Inicializar HTML para el bloque
    let loopHtml = '';
    // Obtener plantilla, lo que está dentro de  ?=  ...  =?
    let template = loop.match(/(\?=)([^\?=].|\s)*(=\?)/m)[0]
        .replace('?=', '').replace('=?', '');
    // Buscar ciclo for, remplazando entidades por caracteres correspondientes
    let forCond = loop.replace('&lt;', '<').replace('&gt;', '>').match(/for\(.*\)/);
    // Separar las 3 expresiones
    let forParts = forCond[0].trim().replace('for(', '').replace(')', '').split(';');
    // Analizar primera expresión, definición de variable y valor de inicio
    let parts1 = forParts[0].replace('let ', '').split('=');
    let letter = (isNaN(parseInt(parts1[0].trim()))) ? parts1[0].trim() : parts1[1].trim();
    let start = (isNaN(parseInt(parts1[0].trim()))) ? parseInt(parts1[1].trim()) : parseInt(parts1[0].trim());
    
    // Analizar segunda expresión, condición para ejecutar
    let end = parseInt(forParts[1].replace(letter, '').replace(/[^\d]/g, '').trim());
    let op = forParts[1].replace(letter, '').replace(/\d/g, '').trim();

    // Analizar tercera expresión, incremento o decremento de variable
    let incVal = forParts[2].trim().replace(letter, '').replace(/[^\d]/g, '') || 1;
    let incOp = forParts[2].trim().replace(letter, '').replace(/\d/g, '');
    
    // Inicializar variable y ciclo
    let i = start;
    while(true) {
        // Agregar plantilla a HTML, remplazando variable
        loopHtml += template.replace('${' + letter + '}', i);
        // ¿Qué se debe hacer con la variable? ¿Incremento, decremento, cuánto?
        if(incOp == '++') {
            i++;
        } else if(incOp == '--') {
            i--;
        } else if(incOp == '+=') {
            i += incVal;
        } else if(incOp == '-=') {
            i -= incVal;
        }
        // ¿Se cumple condición para salir del ciclo?
        if(
            (['<', '>'].includes(op) && i == end)
            || (op == '==' && i != end)
            || (op == '<=' && i > end)
            || (op == '>=' && i < end)
        ) {
            break;
        }
    }
    // Devolver HTML
    return loopHtml;
};

// Obtener HTML del documento
let html = document.body.innerHTML;
// Separar scripts (el fragmento de código agrega todo aquí y complica las cosas)
let scripts = html.split('<script');
let newHtml = '';
/*
  ***** Intenté con esta expresión regular
  ***** pero no funciona como se esperaba
  ***** extrañamente, falla si la etiqueta no es <p>
  ***** y toma mucho tiempo para obtener los bloques de código
    // let loops = html.match(/(\{%)([^\{%].|\s)*(%\})/mg);
*/

// Separar por inicio de bloque
let loops = scripts[0].split('{%');
loops.forEach((loop, index) => {
    // Si no corresponde a un ciclo, solo agregar HTML
    if(index == 0 || !loop.includes('%}')) {
        newHtml += loop;
    } else {
        // Sí es un ciclo, interpretar y agregar a HTML
        // outside puede ser cadena vacía o HTML después del ciclo, como "</div>"
        let [inside, outside] = loop.split('%}');
        newHtml += parseLoop(inside) + outside;
    }
});
// Actualizar HTML del documento, incluyendo scripts
document.querySelector('html').innerHTML = newHtml + '<script' + scripts[1];
```

```html
<div>
    {%
        for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        ?=
            <p>${i}</p>
        =?
    %}
    {%
        for(let x = 10; x >= 5; x--)
        ?=
            <button>${x}</button>
        =?
    %}
</div>
```